# How to check if an object has been modified

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object, for example:

```
var o = {
  a: 1
};
```

The user does:

```
o.a = 2;
```

How can I know if the `o` object has been modified? I cannot touch the `o` object so I cannot use `Object.defineProperties()`.

Comment: Do you want to get notified on every change or just have a way to check it? If you just want to check I would say generate a hashcode of the object and compare when necessary.

Comment: Just have a way to check it, but how can I generate this hash?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are in the node.js environment and thus don't have to care about crappy old JavaScript engines (i.e. old browsers) you can use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to define properties with *accessor functions*. This allows you to execute a custom function whenever a certain property is read/written - so you can simply log the write and e.g. store it in a separate property.

```
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, 'a', {
    get: function() {
        return this.__a;
    },
    set: function(value) {
        this.__a = value;
        this.__a_changed = true;
    }
});
o.__a = 1;
```

Whenever a value is assigned to `o.a` the `__a_changed` property will be set. Of course it would be even cleaner to execute whatever you want to do on change right in the `set` function - but it obviously depends on your code if you can do so in a useful way.

Comment: Same as the first answer, I cannot touch the `o` object because it's created from a config file with a third-party module.

Comment: You could still convert all the plain properties to accessor-backed properties.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing would obviously be to just check if the value is different than what you initialized it as. Another option would be to use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

```
var o = {};
var aValue = 2;
Object.defineProperty(o, "a", { 
    get: function() { return aValue; }, 
    set: function(newValue) { 
        aValue = newValue;
        // trigger event or set flag that it was changed
    } 
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot touch the `o` object because it's created from a config file with a third-party module.

Comment: Assuming you really can't touch the `o` object, you may not have a lot of options other than checking the value against an expected value. There aren't any events that are automatically triggered when a plain ole Object has a property changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could always wrap `o` with your own setter getter if the `defineProperty` doesn't do the job for you.

```
var myO = {
    o: o, // original o
    changed: false,
    set: function (prop, val) {
        this.o[prop] = val;
        this[prop + "IsChanged"] = true;
    },
    get: function (prop) {
       return this.o[prop];
    }
};
myO.set("a", 2);
console.log(myO.aIsChanged); // true
```

A better solution would be to execute an event using something like [`Backbone.Events`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) to exeute someting `myO.on("change", function () { ... })`

```
var myO = {
        o: o, // original o
        changed: false,
        set: function (prop, val) {
            this.o[prop] = val;
            this.trigger("change", prop, val);
        },
        get: function (prop) {
           return this.o[prop];
        }
    };

_.extend(myO, Backbone.events);

myO.on("change", function (prop, val) {
   // Do stuff with the change
});

myO.set("a", 1);
```

I'm using the [`Underscore`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) library's `extend` method here, fyi.

Answer (score -1):

```
var o_backup = o.a;

if(o.a != o_backup){
// function to execute
}
```

Basically, you are just creating a variable which will save the `a` from the object `o` and then you're checking if it has been modified or not.

Also, you can do a `setInterval()` function if you want to check if it has been modified more than once.

Comment: No offense, but this is not a very elegant solution.